# Two Sums JS (forEach)

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to figure out why my code is not working.

```js
const twoSum = function (arr, target) {
  const newMap = new Map();
  const newArr = arr.forEach(function (num, i, arr) {
    if (newMap.has(target - num)) return [newMap.get(target - num), i];
    else newMap.set(num, i);
    console.log(newMap);
  });
  return [];
};

console.log(twoSum([3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3], 9));
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your expected output?

Comment: You can't return early out of a `forEach`, you'll need to use a `for...of` or just a `for` loop, from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#description): *'Note: There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method is the wrong tool.'*. Also `forEach` always returns `undefined` so assigning it to variable is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `return` inside a callback function not in the main function (twoSum()), so the towSum function has only one return `[]` , to avoid that you can use for loop instead as in the `twoSum1()` example, but if you insist to use `.forEach` method, Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function) answer you can use another collback function to receive the return like in the `twoSum2()` exapmle

```js
const twoSum1 = function (nums, target) {
  const newMap = new Map();
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    const num = nums[i];
    if (newMap.has(target - num)) {
      return [newMap.get(target - num), i];
    }
    newMap.set(num, i);
  }
};

console.log("from the first method: ");
console.log(twoSum1([3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3], 9));

const twoSum2 = function (arr, target, fn) {
  const newMap = new Map();
  const newArr = arr.forEach(function (num, i) {
    if (newMap.has(target - num)) fn([newMap.get(target - num), i]);
    else newMap.set(num, i);
  });
  return newArr;
};

twoSum2([3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3], 9, (result) => {
  console.log("from the second method: ");
  console.log(result);
});
```